# WPF prism : developing new modules

Tags: wpf, prism

We have an windows application that runs the trivial way. Is it possible to use Prism for only the new screens or modules we develop for our application without changing the way the main application  is running right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. You will have to do some modification to your main app to work together with Prism: it'll have to load the modules, and it's window(s) must expose one or more containers where Prism can put it's windows. Apart from that nothing changes.

Practically you'll have to implement a Prism BootStrapper (eg derive from `MefBootStrapper`) and run it in App.xaml.cs. And one or more ContentControls with a `RegionName` set where prism can create it's window content.

Comment: OP. This is your answer and describes the process nicely. You need a bootstrapper. You need regions. After that, prism does the heavy lifting. It will work like smooth, creamy butter +1