# How to use PRISM in an existing application?

Tags: wpf, view, prism

We have an existing application which is monolithic and has over 100 screens. We are trying to modularize the entire application. Now we are doing this step by step. Currently we are taking only one or two screens at a time.Since there can only be one shell how can this be integrated with the existing application? If so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF prism : developing new modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608134/wpf-prism-developing-new-modules)

Answer (score 2):

*Using PRISM* can mean quite a lot, starting from using 'DelegateCommand' in an MVVM application. If you talk about the full package to build a modular software on the basis of a monolithic software, it requires a proper redesign. You can't glue the PRISM concept 'on top'.

That being said, the transformation process will have a concept phase at the beginning, where you need to separate the elements on an abstract level: What is shell, what is module, what are interactions between shell and modules and between different modules.

Second, you implement this concept in an abstract way, i.e. define interfaces, composite presentation events, etc., etc.

Afterwards you will be able to use a large part of what you already have. You take the monolithic thing and isolate distinct parts into separate projects with no direct (!) dependencies to other modules or the shell. Every direct dependency is 'translated' into dependencies to the shared interfaces, composite presentation events, etc.

Think about it like this:

What you have:

[image]

What you want:

[image]

So, you need to cut off parts from the big thing and pack it into portions: This can obviously not be done if you want to keep the big thing...